# add _blank when object is active

Tags: jquery, object

I would like all links to become _blank (open in new page) when an object has started playing or is focussed...

I figured the best way to do this would be with some jQuery, but i am not quite sure how to hook into the Object.

This is what i came up with so far;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#podcast").focus(function(){
("a").attr('target','_blank');
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Not surprisingly, it doesn't work!

Any ideas on this, guys?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You've skipped the jQuery selector. This is your corrected code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#podcast").click(function(){
     $("a").attr({'target':'_blank'}); /* Here, at the first character, you forgot $ */
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Example working: http://jsfiddle.net/QzKPE/

Comment: Thanks for that - but still does not seem to work... I am not sure that it is picking up on a .click or .focus on the object with #podcast when it's clicked.... any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry - but i think you have missunderstood... The object is 'player'. Once that player is playing, i need all links on that page to have _blank added - so when the user clicks away, they can continue listening to that player.

Comment: Still no joy! :( Although that code certainly looks like it SHOULD do what i want...

Comment: There's an example of how it should work, and it actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/QzKPE/

Comment: Hmmm... do you think that it matters that whats being clicked is an <object id="podcast">?

Comment: Object is for including flash. There are some problems with that. Read this: http://progproblems.blogspot.com/2009/08/javascript-onclick-for-flash-embeded.html

Comment: Thanks Ryan - had a read through and applied the necessary changes and still now luck! You can view the web page here; http://culturecuts.co.uk/culture-casts/instrumental-hiphop/night-market-mixtape/

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Unfortunately, the code still does not work though! Any more suggestions? :s

Comment: It works for me if you put this:

`<object width="300" height="480" id="podcast" onclick="$('a').attr({'target':'_blank'});">` on the object ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").attr('target','_blank');
```

:-)